# data conversion from varchar to decimal

Tags: sql-server

I have a column with varchar data type. I need to convert it into decimal data type in sql server 2014?
For example, varchar value .0462500 into decimal 4.62500

I have seen some similar questions in so, but it didn't work for me.

Thank you for your time and  help!

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far? This is a great place to start: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What exactly have you tried and how is it "didn't work" for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your `VARCHAR` variables will require roughly the same conversion rate, you could simply use the [`CAST()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function to convert them and then perform the necessary multiplication :

```
SELECT CAST(YourValue AS DECIMAL(7,5)) * 100
```

Likewise the [`CONVERT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method will essentially accomplish the same thing via a different syntax :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,5),YourValue) * 100
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rion Willoams

Comment: Hi @AnjanaH if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: @Rion Williams . Your answer was exactly what I wanted. Thanks Rion. I marked it  as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) or [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) functions.

**Convert**:

```
select convert(decimal(10,5),.0462500)*100
```

**Cast**:

```
select cast(.0462500 as decimal(10,5))*100
```

Note: If there is malformed data(data which can not be converted), you may need to use [Try_Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) or [Try_Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) functions instead.

**Try_Convert**:

```
select try_convert(decimal(10,5),.0462500)*100
```

**Try_Parse**:

```
select try_parse('.0462500' as decimal(10,5))*100
```